# What's the meaning of "Minimal Degenerate Trees"

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree, red-black-tree

I would like to ask:
What does *minimal degenerate tree* mean?

And how do they look in comparison to

- AVL trees,
- binary search trees,
- R-B trees (Red-Black trees)

of height 3.

Comment: Degenerate means that the the tree is so unbalanced that it became a linked list. Never heard of minimal though. Also red-black trees and AVL are always balanced due to it's algorithm, binary search trees can be degenerative (i.e, 5, 6, 7)

Comment: I would think a minimal degenerate tree would either be empty or have only one node, but I too have never come across this term before.